# Using splunk to plot table of key counts extracted from JSON string field

Tags: logging, splunk

I want to use splunk to plot a graph from my service's payload logs to highlight the type of query parameters. The logs are of this format:

```
2020-11-10 04:46:57.471  INFO InfoType="payload" request="{"queryParams":{"field1":"26453451364"}}" 

2020-11-10 04:46:57.471  INFO InfoType="payload" request="{"queryParams":{"field2":"71362547612531"}}" 

2020-11-10 04:46:57.471  INFO InfoType="payload" request="{"queryParams":{"field3":"71547612531", "field4":"7136254761"}}"
```

For the above, I want output to be something like this:

```
Query Param   | Count
--------------------
field1        |  1
--------------------
field2        |  1
--------------------
field3,field4 |  1
```

I tried a lot with spath, but I am not able to get it to work.

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="2020-11-10 04:46:57.471  INFO InfoType=\"payload\" request=\"{\"queryParams\":{\"field1\":\"26453451364\"}}\""
| spath input=request path={}.queryParams
```

Any help on how to proceed or what I am doing wrong will be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

It appears your JSON has multivalue fields

Try using [`mvexpand`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/mvexpand) first:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp
| mvexpand queryParams
| stats count by queryParams
| rename queryParams as "Query Param"
```